# Getting this types of err when i am trying to send transaction from web3 using biconomy

Tags: javascript, web3js

Getting this types of err when i am trying to send transaction from web3 using biconomy

```
code: -32603
data: {code: 3, message: "execution reverted: Please add some good amount", data: "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000…1646420736f6d6520676f6f6420616d6f756e740000000000"}
message: "Internal JSON-RPC error.
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

Transaction amount > Wallet Balance Available

gas: 36000

gasPrice: '20000000000'